# Jerkson JsonMappingException

Tags: json, scala

I'm trying to serialize scala case class to JSON string using Jerkson like this:

```
case class Page(title: String, id: String, ls: List[(String, String, Int)])
val pageList = new mutable.ArrayBuffer[Page]()
val jsonString = Json.generate(pageList)
```

`pageList` is extremely large with several million `Page` objects. 
The call fails with this exception:

> Caused by: org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException:
>   [no message for java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that you've got "several million" objects, I'm guessing you might be hitting the length limit of `String`. Try generating to an `OutputStream`, ie, `Json.generate(pageList, out)`.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to consider using a Streaming solution. You can use one of the the Jackson Streaming APIs:

```
JsonGenerator jg = jsonFactory.createJsonGenerator(file, JsonEncoding.UTF8); // or Stream, Reader
```

or, you can use a TokenBuffer (which is considered best practice for some situations):

```
TokenBuffer buffer = new TokenBuffer();
// serialize object as JSON tokens (but don't serialize as JSON text!)
objectMapper.writeValue(buffer, myBean);
```

Details: [Jackson Streaming Documentation](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonStreamingApi)